# Missing files on shared NTFS partition

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, ntfs

I'm somewhat new to Ubuntu. I have set my laptop up with a dual boot win8/ubuntu 12.04 each with their own partition and a third empty data partition with the intention of working on files between the two operating systems. After copying some files to the data partition in Ubuntu and then rebooting into a hibernating windows 8 the files had disappeared. I tried repairing the file system in windows 8 and the folder containing the files reappeared however the files themselves are no longer there.

How do I start going about diagnosing this problem? It's critical for me that the files on the data partition are stable, should I consider not using ntfs and forget sharing the files between the two operating systems?